# Printing Hebrew UTF-8 produces giberish

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I try to print a stirng and for some reason it's turn into gibrish. But if I put it in an online utf 8 convertr it works (https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-decode). 
And the output i get is: "×ª×™×›×•×Ÿ ×“×” ×©×œ×™×˜" 
instead of: "תיכוןדהשליט" that I get in the website and is the orignal stirg.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print '\xd7\xaa\xd7\x99\xd7\x9b\xd7\x95\xd7\x9f \xd7\x93\xd7\x94 \xd7\xa9\xd7\x9c\xd7\x99\xd7\x98'
```

Comment: The output from the website I had in the link is the correct output and for someone reason I get the other resulet(I will edit my question to make it clearer).

Comment: `print my_string.decode('utf8')`

Comment: Yep, I you are right kindda my bad I didnt get the whole conept of encoding right and thought that I need to encode into utf8 or something like this.

Comment: I can't reproduce in python 2.7: https://repl.it/repls/CompetitiveVictoriousDiskdrive

Comment: @chrisz he is running it in his terminal I think which is not decoding it with utf8 but with something else(latin1 i think) ... (repl.it is probably doing some encoding mojo behind the scenes)

Comment: So what are you printing **to**? This isn't a Python problem, you have valid UTF-8. But your *terminal* or *console* must be configured to expect UTF-8 for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to decode the bytes back into unicode with utf8 encoding ... by default its using whatever your terminal is using(probably latin1) ... your terminal **may not support all of the characters ***  (see https://repl.it/repls/OnlyRewardingKeyboardmacro)

`print '\xd7\xaa\xd7\x99\xd7\x9b\xd7\x95\xd7\x9f \xd7\x93\xd7\x94 \xd7\xa9\xd7\x9c\xd7\x99\xd7\x98'.decode('utf8')`